# Problema para passar uma variavel de um form para outro

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

beleza?
Estou com um problema em um login de um sistema que estou criando, na qual de acordo com o tipo do usuário do cliente, ele abrirá o próximo form com alguns componentes visíveis ou não. Quando dou um sout na variável no form login (que recebe o campo "tipo" do banco de dados) ela aparece, agora se eu faço o mesmo já no form do menu, acaba dando "null" no terminal ou seja, a variável não está transitando. Detalhe é que quando escrevi o código pela primeira vez funcionou, o que acontece aqui??? 
Obs: sou técnico em informática, possuo conhecimento básico/intermediário sobre Java, queria a opinião de vocês e o que fariam pra resolver. Desde já agradeço!

Código do form login(eu chamei o método tentativa no botão de entrar e no evento KeyEvent):

```
private final Connection connection;

public static String tipo;

public void tentativa() {

    String login = txt_usuario.getText().trim();

    try {


            String sql = "SELECT tipo FROM usuario WHERE login = '" + login + "'";

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                tipo = rs.getString("tipo");
                System.out.println(tipo);
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

Código do form menu:

```
public String tipo = "";

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

/**
 * Creates new form form_menu
 */
public form_menu() {
    initComponents();
    this.setTipo(form_login.tipo);
    System.out.println(tipo);
}
```

Comment: antigamente a maioria dos programas em java utilizavam o JDBC mas a JPA veio para facilitar isso, porque não utiliza a JPA? se tratando de seu código ele está incompleto. veja isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1

Comment: Depois que é feito o login, lá no `form_menu()` se fizer isso `System.out.println(Connection.tipo)` qual o resultado?

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria passar o valor de tipo ao iniciar o form do Menu, assim o seu form Login chamaria o form Menu e passaria como parâmetro para o construtor o valor de tipo, o código ficaria parecido com isso:

Código do form login(eu chamei o método tentativa no botão de entrar e no evento KeyEvent):

```
private final Connection connection;

public static String tipo;

public void tentativa() {

    String login = txt_usuario.getText().trim();

    try {


            String sql = "SELECT tipo FROM usuario WHERE login = ?";

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            stmt.setString(1,login);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                tipo = rs.getString("tipo");
                JFormMenu menu = new Menu(tipo);
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

Código do form menu:

```
public String tipo = "";

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

/**
 * Creates new form form_menu
 */
public form_menu(String tipoRecebido) {
    initComponents();
    this.setTipo(tipoRecebido);
    System.out.println(tipo);
}
```

Recomendo ler este [artigo do DevMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/dicas-como-passar-parametros-entre-2-forms/5791).

Comment: Só uma observação, não é aconcelhavel essa consulta sql contatenada, já que da pra burlar com um sql injection.
O ideal é fazer via stmt.setString(1,"login")

Comment: Editei a resposta para ficar de acordo com a forma mais adequada.